# Renaming multiple files with correct numerical order in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have .mp3 files in my folder with these names: 2.mp3,4.mp3,6.mp3,8.mp3,10.mp3,12.mp3,...102.mp3,104.mp3...
and would like to rename them all and get following result: 0001.mp3,0002.mp3,0003.mp3,0004.mp3...

the following code changes the names of all files, but the problem is that it does not change/sort them in the exact original order as they are originally displayed in my folder.

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('{0:D4}.mp3' -f $i++)}
```

Something like this written below I want to achieve

- 2.mp3 -> 0001.mp3
- 4.mp3 -> 0002.mp3
- 6.mp3 -> 0003.mp3
- 8.mp3 -> 0004.mp3
- 10.mp3 -> 0005.mp3
- 12.mp3 -> 0006.mp3
- ...

I have currently come to this half-solution that does not work and I do not know how to proceed/solve this problem.

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName {'{0:D4}.mp3' -f [int]($_.BaseName -replace '\D') $i++ }}
```

Comment: "I have currently come to this half-solution that does not work" - what's wrong with it?

Comment: Just remove `$i++` from your half-solution and it should work.

Comment: you can save the `G-CI` call to an array and then use the index number plus `1` to derive the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Sort-Object` to sort them according to the numerical value in the name before you start renaming:

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 |Sort-Object {[int]($_.BaseName -replace '\D')} | Rename-Item ...
```

Although you may run into unexpected errors because `$i++` does not have the effect you intend - the `++` operation creates a new local copy of `$i` without ever incrementing `$i` in the parent scope.

We can solve that by explicitly passing a *reference* to `$i`:

```
$i = 1
Get-ChildItem *.mp3 |Sort-Object {[int]($_.BaseName -replace '\D')} | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0:D4}.mp3' -f ([ref]$i).Value++}
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias for your time and help!